# How to correctly get android image size

Tags: android

I've an app which need the user to select an image and then extract some info from the image.

```
Intent getIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    getIntent.setType("image/*");

                    Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    pickIntent.setType("image/*");

                    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(getIntent, "Select Image");
                    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[]{pickIntent});


                     startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CODE_REQUEST_SCREENSHOT);
```

this is to start a file picker for images, then for the result

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CODE_REQUEST_SCREENSHOT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {

    final Cursor returnCursor = getContentResolver().query(data.getData(), null, null, null, null);
                returnCursor.moveToFirst();
                final int size = (int) returnCursor.getLong(returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE)) > 1 ? (int) returnCursor.getLong(returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE)) : (int) new File(data.getData().getPath()).length();
      if (size < 1)
                    FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().recordException(new RuntimeException("screenshot size == " + size + " " + data.getData().toString()));
    
    
    }
```

The app is currently in production and for some images users get the `size == 0` (we are talking about image files I doubt any user has a file in his phone that is larger than a Integer)

I wasn't able to reproduce the error in dev [i mean that for the devices i've available to test all files return a valid size]

The errors i detected happen in **android 10**, in **motorola phones** [but it might be just coincidence due small sample]

What I'm doing wrong? is there a real issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking the scheme of the `Uri` that you get back. If it is `content`, then your `query()` is reasonable, but the `File` check is not (as it is not a file). If the scheme is `file`, then the `File` check is worth a try, but your `query()` is pointless at best (and probably crashes).

You also do not include `CATEGORY_OPENABLE` on your `Intent` objects — that will limit you to data sources that are somewhat more likely to implement the `OpenableColumns` and let you do something useful with the content (e.g., read it in).

But, beyond that, there is no requirement for every `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and `ACTION_PICK` implementation to support the `OpenableColumns` and return a non-zero size.

Comment: the ACTION_GET_CONTENT should be in which of the intents? both?
so what if they dont support OpenableColumns ? I need to read the whole inputstream to get the file size? that looks weird

Comment: @RafaelLima: "the ACTION_GET_CONTENT should be in which of the intents?" -- if you mean `CATEGORY_OPENABLE`, then it should be at least in the `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` `Intent`. I do not use `ACTION_PICK` much for file content and so I forget the rules for it. "I need to read the whole inputstream to get the file size? that looks weird " -- then live without the size, I guess.